# Unity animation transition glitches back to last animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 3d

So, I have my animation and it goes to an empty state.
The thought behind this is that it goes to it's default no animation state.
However, before it does that, it glitches back in to the old animation.
I tested it, it only happens whenever I go from an animation to an empty state.
It always glitches for the same amount of time for each transition, however it is different for each transition.
I have never seen something like this before, does anyone of you know the problem?

The animation

[image: Animation]

The clear state

[image]

The transition

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by glitching? I am going to take a guess and say you do not want an exit timer, so uncheck this box.

[image: Uncheck this]

An exit timer is just used to transition between two states and will take the amount of time to wait to transition. In your transition block, it also shows you stacking your two animations which might be why everything looks weird for a short time. Instead of an exit timer, you might want to use [`parameters`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) to change your states or directly set them in code.

The other possible issue is the checkbox [`Write Defaults`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html).

From the [`Unity Docs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html), the description of `Write Defaults` is

> Whether or not the AnimatorStates writes back the default values for
> properties that are not animated by its Motion.

Unexpected behavior with animators can be caused by `Write Defaults` if you are not familiar with how they work or what they do. Again, it is hard to say what exactly is wrong with the description of your issue. Try unchecking each of these boxes individually and seeing if either one fixes your issue. If that does not work, try both and if that does not work, let me know what your issue is in more detail. Possibly attach a gif or video showing what is breaking as the written description is not helping too much.

Comment: I have found another way to solve it(the dirty way, just using creating an unactive animation), but thanks for answering.
I am still going to accept your answer because it probably was the clean way to do this, and maybe I'll use it in my next projext too :)